# Why are grain coatings an important mechanism for preserving porosity during burial in sandstone but not in carbonate?

Tags: geology, petrology

I am writing a paper on the role of petroleum emplacement and grain coatings in preserving porosity during burial. I can find many sources discussing grain coatings stopping cementation in sandstone, but cannot find any information whatsoever about grain coatings in carbonate strata. What causes that difference in the importance of grain coatings?